# How to select after a word beginning of a line?

Tags: regex

I want to select words after `Title:` using regular expression search, how do I do that?
[Example with:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj6UN.png)

I've tried `(?<=Title: ).*(?=\s)` but didn't work on the 3rd one.

```
Title: Select after title.
Description: Again below.

Title: Some random text.
Description: Text goes here.

Title: Test.
Description: Title: This will not be selected.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is very straightforward.

Comment: I have tried `(?<=Title: ).*(?=\s)` but it selected on the 3rd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include start of the line anchor to match the beginning of a line.

```
(?<=^Title: ).+
```

or

```
^Title:\s*(.+)
```

or

```
^Title:\s*\K.+
```